# jquery-autocomplete: serviceUrl to filter results presented in lookupFilter()

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery-autocomplete

I am using the [jQuery-Autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) library for an input field but instead of targeting local data for the suggestions I want to use `serviceUrl`, which provides to the script a JSON file with the list of files. In the [demo](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/blob/master/scripts/demo.js) (lines 30-47) provided by the library author  I then replace `lookup: countriesArray,` with `serviceUrl: 'retrieve_foreign_countries.php',`.

```
<?php // retrieve_foreign_countries.php

include 'init_db.php';
include 'functions.php';

prepareForeignCountriesJson($db);

?>
```

with `prepareForeignCountriesJson()` defined as

```
function prepareForeignCountriesJson($db) {

  $sql = 'SELECT country_code AS code, country_name AS value FROM foreign_country ORDER BY value;';
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  echo "{\"query\": \"Unit\", \"suggestions\": ".json_encode($result)."}";

}
```

The lookup when entering some text works just fine BUT doesn't filter the result according to the input text and instead provides the whole list of countries. In other words the function (in the [demo](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/blob/master/scripts/demo.js) at lines 34-37)

```
 lookupFilter: function(suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
var re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi');
return re.test(suggestion.value);
},
```

doesn't kick in since, as explained by the library author ([here](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/issues/206#issuecomment-49866912))

> When using serviceUrl option, it is server responsibility to filter
>   results.

Then, where do I start to obtain with my `serviceUrl` the same results of when loading local data? Do I need to filter the lookup data in my `prepareForeignCountriesJson()`? But how many times `prepareForeignCountriesJson()` is called? Every time the user enters some character in the field?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your SELECT is missing the WHERE clause:

```
$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE country_name LIKE CONCAT('$prefix', '%') ORDER BY ...";
```

(Note that I changed to double quotes so I could 'interpolate' $prefix.)